# How can I add a link in the response of api.ai chatbot web chat control/iframe

Tags: dialogflow-es

As the title suggests please help me regarding this issue. I am trying to add a link in the response in the web chat control/iframe. Assistant extension with link to open does not seem to work for me. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no rich format for Web Demo (no images, link...).
However, you can set HTML Code in Text Response and write your own Web Chat.